# Get modified array of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
const availAbleData = [{id:1,name:'user1'},{id:2,name:'user2'},{id:3,name:'user3'},{id:4,name:'user5'},{id:5,name:'user5'},{id:6,name:'user6'}];

const selectedIds=[1,2,3,4];
```

I want to display an new array of object from "availAbleData" which has ids from "selectedIds" array

Comment: filter and includes might help. or convert the selectedIds to a set and use filter and has

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter method

```
const filteredData = availAbleData.filter(item => selectedIds.includes(item.id));
```